# How do I find the result of a find, in this script for sending by email

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, unix

How do I find the result of a find, in this script for sending by email ??

I've tried this way

How do I put the result within the email.
The result of find

```
mailx -s "result of find " support@systems.com
```

Comment: `find` as in the `find` command. Eh? If so, `find` what?

Comment: Please try to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get the best help and information with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would meet your needs:

```
find /path_to_examine -type f -print | mailx -s "Find Results" support@systems.com
```

`mailx` expects its input from STDIN; either read from the initiating terminal (and terminated with a control-D sequence); or redirected; or piped.  The example chosen uses a pipe.  You could also redirect an already created file, thusly:

```
mailx -s "Find Results" support@systems.com < myresults
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to "pipe" it.

```
find /bin | mailx -s "result of find in /bin" support@systems.com
```

Pipes allow you to transfer the output of a shell command into input of another command. They are very convenient and widely use in the linux/unix systems.
You should look into it.